# Error in one Javascript function causes others to stop working

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

This is a general question to get information about how things work. I can post some sample code if anyone needs more explanation.

I have a substantial program in ColdFusion 8, which includes about 8 javascript functions.  If one function, call it NW, is not working, perhaps because I lost a curly bracket, some of the others may not work until I fix the bug.  I was trying to think what connections there might be between these functions. Where a function calls NW I could understand that it might fail to function if NW is broken.  However, the same problem occurs if both are called from the same element, NW with an "onchange" and OtherFunction with an "onclick", although neither is calling the other, and they are not connected in any other way.

Could someone explain to me what is going on "under the hood"?  I don't understand why these separate functions are intertwined in this way.

Comment: Betty, you definitely should post the code samples to clarify what exactly you cannot understand. Currently your question is not very constructive and may be closed.

Comment: From your profile: "jhave designed"

Comment: Could you explain why these small errors matter so much to you that you would spend time finding and fixing them?

Answer (score 2):

Because JavaScript is an interpreted language, syntax errors that are 'fatal' aren't caught until you run the code. They can also have a cascading effect.

e.g:

```
function nw(){

/* some code */

function otherFunction(){
 /* other code*/
}
```

Notice that because I missed the end curly brace of `function nw()` the interpreter won't close `nw()` and this `otherFunction` is a closure within `nw`, but because it's not closed with a curly brace it can't run `nw` or its now assumed closure. So neither function will work.

Coldfusion also adds its own JS on some pages which can make the process harder to debug.

Hope this is relevant but it sounds like what you're experiencing.

Comment: This makes perfect sense for curly bracket omissions.  However, if there is any syntax error within the function, such as failure to pair ( and ) in an if statement, all the functions will not run, even if I've properly ended the function with the bug.

Comment: With a syntax error the interpreter cannot continue running past the point the error occurs. If you second function is defined at any point after, or possible with the same frame of reference as the funciton with the error then the interpreter would stop dead and the second funciton won't be run. code samples would help give  a clearer answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting to close a curly bracket make all your javascript invalid until he could find one as a function declaration or conditional statement needs both: the js engine won't look at the code inside until you have a valid structured code.

If you have no dependency between you js functions, then the only reason why it could break is an error in the javascript syntax. If you refer to a non existing variable in a function for example, it will stop when this specific function is called. All other ones should run fine. Also when a function failed at a certain time, usually all your js code will stop working after that.

Hope it make sense, but giving more details would need to see the code... it's my attempt to a generic explanation :-)

Comment: Thanks Cyril -- that seems to account for some of it, but not all of it.   I didn't include code because there were so many cases -- but next time I will show some code.