# using social sharing buttons from addthis.com

Tags: javascript, html, css, addthis

Hey so I have chosen to use the social sharing widgets that are provided by addthis.com basically becuase I thought they would make my life easier, and they provide alot of data analytics free of charge. 
I through them into my sight without problem added metatags for facebook and everything worked perfectly on the homepage. sharing works exactly how id like it to. However i then navigated a way from home page elsewhere in site and they don't appear (I embedded them into a top panel wich occurs on everyage on the site, all same php script to print and css to format).  Now ive looked at the source code for both homepage and other and it appears that add this is not pushing required data inside the tags on anywhere other then the homepage. I'm woundering if anyone else has run into this problem or can suggest a solution. You can check out the problem
[homepage here](http://ec2-50-17-75-42.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) and the [problem page here](http://ec2-50-17-75-42.compute-1.amazonaws.com/series.php?series=Arctic_Air) or just navigate from home page to anyother page to view problem page. any help with why this might be happening or how to fix would be awesome.

Note: I also posted similar post on addthis.com forum a few hours ago but because it sucks/ I can't even find my post I'm asking SO to help if they can!

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com would probably be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Check javascript errors: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword - var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: @UpTheCreek I will do this  thanks.

Comment: @showdev my java console does not propagate an error of this type (on chrome canary) i have no error's associated with javascript just two on missing reaources. what browser are you using?

Comment: @brendanmorrison I see the error in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. It's in funcs.js on line 51. It might be an unrelated error, but could be preventing your AddThis from loading.

Comment: ahh sorry this is an unrelated error I am pretty sure, though ill look  into fixing it and see what happens, thanks for the help

Comment: @showdev thanks alot... the error was from a script in head that wasn't for this page but it some how fixed the problem by removing the script, not to sure why this is any ideas? (for my own curiousity) ... if you'd like to copy your original comment to an answer I'll accept it and give up vote. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a javascript error in funcs.js on line 51. While this may be an error unrelated to AddThis, it could be preventing other javascript from being performed. Javascript errors can have a "cascading" effect.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword - var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
funcs.js line 51
```

More info on this here: [Error in one Javascript function causes others to stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516346/error-in-one-javascript-function-causes-others-to-stop-working)